# Accidental usage of a complicated tense structure

Tags: tenses, present-perfect

Here I found myself, on the second day of new year, writing a comment, in which I unintentionally used an overly complicated tense structure, that left me clueless.

> Lately there have been plenty of new Cyberpunk books being released, that haven't yet managed to garner as broad an audience as the genre classics have over all those years.

If I want to stress the continuity of new books sprouting to this very day, can I put this the way I did? And is the sentence structure correct, or should I change the order of some words?

How else would you change it to make it sound more natural?

Comment: I'm reminded of a comment in a similar situation by John Lawler: It's grammatical, but that's about the only good thing you can say about it. Although 'all those years' is brave without an overt referent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I should say that while there would be arguments about just what was "a classic" and just what did and did not fit the genre (and why), there'd be enough general agreement that those classics came out in the late 80s and perhaps the early 90s, and "all those years" is hence 20–30 years.

Comment: So perhaps if I broke the sentence to just "Lately there have been plenty of new Cyberpunk books being released, that haven't yet managed to garner a broader audience." it would sound a lot better? Or is the first part of the sentence the main problem?

Comment: Why do you feel you need a comma at all?

Comment: Just a bad habit derived from my first language. But other than that - it's better now?

Comment: "Lately, plenty of new Cyberpunk books have been released that haven't managed to garner as broad an audience as the classics of the genre."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - We're living in a time of brave new words.

Comment: @Erik Kowal Distinguishing between an en-dash and an em-dash is none too easy with smoke signals. And what you mean, 'We'...?

Answer (score 1):

"Lately" doesn't normally include the future; that's why combining it with the present progessive "being released" seems odd. "Have been" specifically excludes the future, so there's even more of a conflict with the present progressive. I would change "lately there have been" to "these days there are" to convey a sense of current continuation. But it does leave out any of the past farther ago than "these days", (which does include some vague portion of the immediate past) One could simply take out "being", but that would go against your expressed desired to convey a sense of continuation.  Or you could clarify further with a more complicated construction : "Lately there have been plenty . . .  released, (and they continue to be released), which . . . "  —this is more precise, but definitely not "more natural".  (by the way "which" calls for a comma, whereas "that" doesn't. But if you use "that", it leaves the possibility that some of them might have garnered such attention, but that you are speaking only of those that haven't. So I think 
", which" is what you mean, to refer to all that have been recently released or are currently being released.)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I just got tangled in an excessive amount of tenses, trying to convey something not entirely logical, is that right? In that case, how about changing my desired sentence to something more along the lines of: "These days there are many new Cyberpunk books being released which haven't yet garnered a broader audience"? It seems the simplier the better, but for some reason I'm continuously trying to make things more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Lately there have been plenty of new Cyberpunk books being released,
>   that haven't yet managed to garner as broad an audience as the genre
>   classics have over all those years.

Many new Cyberpunk books have been released in the past few years, but their audience is not as broad as that garnered by classics of the genre.